# Issue with deploying Django on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Hi Guys I tried deploying my first django on heroku and i am frequently facing issues with the deployment.

I think this is something to do with my settings.py file.
I am clearly unaware with this issue python manage.py collectstatic--noinput , but i have written everything .

Thanks in Advance for help and ideas.

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic--noinput
Traceback(most recent call last): File "manage.py",
line 21,
in <module>
           main()
         File "manage.py", line 17, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
           self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
           output = self.handle(*args, **options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
           collected = self.collect()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 104, in collect
           for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 130, in list
           for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
           directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 316, in listdir
           for entry in os.scandir(path):
       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_6613795b_/static'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

This is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for plausibility_annotation_framework project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG']

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['shrouded-plateau-87096.herokuapp.com/', '127.0.0.1']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'annotating.apps.AnnotatingConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'plausibility_annotation_framework.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'plausibility_annotation_framework.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'annotating-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu need to keep only one of the following lines in settings.py file.

#use this

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

## or this

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

not both in settings.py file

Also, You can use command like:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Thanks , Prabhjot . That worked but a new issue came up

Comment: Please, let me know what's the issue.